# Implement a procedure remove that takes in a list and returns a new list with all instances of item removed from lst

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (filter-lst fn lst)
    'YOUR-CODE-HERE
    (if (null? lst)
        lst
        (if (fn (car lst))
            (cons (car lst)
                  (filter-lst fn (cdr lst))
                  )
            (filter-lst fn (cdr lst))
            )
        )
    )
```

Implement a procedure remove that takes in a list and returns a new list with all instances of item removed from lst. You may assume the list will only consist of numbers and will not have nested lists.

Hint: You might find the filter-lst procedure useful.

my code below:

```
(define (remove item lst)
    'YOUR-CODE-HERE
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
     (equal? item (car (lst))(remove item (cdr lst)))
            (else (cons (car lst)(remove item (cdr (lst)))))
            )
  )
;;; Tests
(remove 3 null)
; expect ()
(remove 3 '(1 3 5))
; expect (1 5)
(remove 5 '(5 3 5 5 1 4 5 4))
; expect (3 1 4 4)
```

My code went wrong!

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '(1 3 5)
```

Can some one help me fix it orz

Comment: Why did you choose to ignore the suggestion to use `filter-lst`?

Comment: In your code: `(car (lst))` this takes the `car` of the pair produced by calling the procedure `lst` with no arguments. Isn't `lst` a list and not a procedure? In Python it resembles `car(lst())` and python says `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: Another thing in your `cond` the first term the predicate is `(null? lst)` while in the second one the predicate is the variable `equal?` which you're using as a value and not a procedure and it is never `#f` so your `else` term will never hit. This is due to missing parentheses in your second term as it probably was meant to be `[(equal? item (car lst)) ...]`

Comment: Since you're given the `filter-lst` function, I think you're expected to use that to implement `remove`, rather than writing all the logic again.

Comment: The hint is a hint that this is easy if you call `filter-lst` in your procedure. If you don't understand how to do that, it is a hint that you should study it in more detail, not that you should go ahead without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop over the list in `remove`. As the instructions say:

> Hint: You might find the filter-lst procedure useful.

So you just have to write a procedure that returns true for values that aren't the same as `item`, and pass this as the `fn` argument to `filter-lst`.

```
(define (remove item lst))
  (filter-lst (lambda (x) (not (= x item))) lst))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you wrote an almost correct "remove" from scratch, here is how to make it work

```lisp
(define (remove item lst)
    'YOUR-CODE-HERE
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          ((equal? item (car lst)) (remove item (cdr lst)))
          (else (cons (car lst) (remove item (cdr lst))))))
```

I've replaced two `(lst)` by `lst` in `(car (lst))` and `(cdr (lst))`. You meant `(car lst)` and `(cdr lst)`. `(car (lst))` would be the first element of the result of a call to `lst`, which makes no sense, since `lst` is not callable (it is not a procedure; which is what the error message is complaining about).

I've also added a `(` before the second condition, to fulfill `cond` syntax: `(cond  (condition  result) (condition result) ... (condition result) (else result))`. You had a `(equal? item (car lst)) (remove item (cdr lst))` here. Which is interpreted as two (unfit) pair `(condition result)`. To make `(equal? item (car lst))` the condition and `(remove item (cdr lst))` the associated result, you need to enclose both in parenthesis, to make the `condition/result` association. Exactly as you already did around condition `(null? lst)` and result `'()`.

But of course, as others pointed out, the expected code is probably not this one (which could be inspired by `filter-lst` but doesn't use it).

You are most certainly expected to

```
(define (remove item lst) (filter-lst (lambda (x) (not (equal? x item))) lst))
```